# How to use vue-recaptcha with Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt3, vue-recaptcha

I have tried using vue-recaptcha with Nuxt as per documentation.

But this doesn't seems to be working out.

I get these errors

```
TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".vue" for C:\Users\Raja Sekhar\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\om-frontend-v0.1\node_modules\vue-recaptcha\dist\components\ChallengeV2.vue
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would help you or not but I had dealt with same issue and ended up using google's js file in the HTML head and used 2.0.3 version of vue-recaptcha.

I'm using Vue 3 with Cli and here how I did it.

1. Get keys from Google recaptcha - https://www.google.com/recaptcha
2. Install vue-recaptcha 2.0.6 from here https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-recaptcha/v/2.0.3
3. Instead of using js from that package, use google's in your index.html file

   `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js`

I had tried with package files but it throwed some errors related to vue, may be because of i'm using the latest one.

4. Include the recaptcha tag with site key in your component like this.

   `<vue-recaptcha @verify="verifyCaptcha" sitekey="site_key">`
5. Import controller in the component and you also may assign the validated value to a variable like this.

   `import { VueRecaptcha } from 'vue-recaptcha';
    export default{
        components:{
            VueRecaptcha
        },
        data : function(){
            captcha:null
        },
        methods : {
            verifyCaptcha: function(theval){
               this.captcha = theval;
            }
        }
    }`

It executes verifyCaptcha method each time the captcha gets validated successfully.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this helps,  but if fixed this error by making sure i had both v2 and v3 keys in the config,  even if you only use one.